# C# Linq creating of XDoc duplicating grouped information

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to create an XDocument by combining two queries. One of the queries is grouped. The issue I have is that the grouped information is duplicating and iterating through the collection.

Group Query:

```
XDocument testing = XDocument.Load(testXMLPath);
var xlWarranty = (from warranty in testing.Descendants("Warranty")
                    select new
                    {
                        Service = (string)warranty.Element("ServiceLevelDescription").Value,
                        Provider = (string)warranty.Element("ServiceProvider").Value,
                        StartDate = (string)warranty.Element("StartDate").Value,
                        EndDate = (string)warranty.Element("EndDate").Value,
                        TypeOfWarranty = (string)warranty.Element("EntitlementType").Value
                    }).ToList();
```

Standard Query:

```
var xlBaseInfo = (from asset in testing.Descendants("DellAsset")
                    select new
                    {
                        Product = (string)asset.Element("MachineDescription").Value,
                        OrderNumber = (string)asset.Element("OrderNumber").Value,
                        ServiceTag = (string)asset.Element("ServiceTag").Value,
                        ShipDate = (string)asset.Element("ShipDate").Value
                    }).ToList();
```

Creation of XDoc:

```
var groupByWarrany = xlWarranty.GroupBy(x => x.Service);
var newDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("Machine", xlBaseInfo.Select(z =>
    new XElement("Asset",
        new XElement("Product", z.Product),
        new XElement("OrderNumber", z.OrderNumber),
        new XElement("ServiceTag", z.ServiceTag),
        new XElement("ShipDate", z.ShipDate),
        //Duplicating information and not moving on to next starting here -- 
        new XElement("Warranties", groupByWarrany.Select(x =>
            new XElement("Warranty",
                new XElement("ServiceDescription", x.Key)
                )))))));
```

**Sample of result**:

```
<Machine>
  <Asset>
    <Product>OPTI 3020,TIGRISSFFFBTX</Product>
    <OrderNumber>584290163</OrderNumber>
    <ServiceTag>1CZTF02</ServiceTag>
    <ShipDate>2014-03-21T00:00:00</ShipDate>
    <Warranties>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>Silver Premium Support</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        **<ServiceDescription>Dell Labor Support</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>4 Hour On-Site Service</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
    </Warranties>
  </Asset>
  <Asset>
    <Product>POWEREDGE R720XD, ORCA S PE</Product>
    <OrderNumber>339791846</OrderNumber>
    <ServiceTag>1VF0TW1</ServiceTag>
    <ShipDate>2013-03-20T00:00:00</ShipDate>
    <Warranties>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>DirectLine Service</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>Keep Your Hard Drive Service</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>Next Business Day Support</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>Silver Premium Support</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>Dell Labor Support</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
      <Warranty>
        <ServiceDescription>4 Hour On-Site Service</ServiceDescription>
      </Warranty>
    </Warranties>
```

The second asset node should not contain those warranties. It is not iterating through the collection.

Comment: Added sample of what is created

Comment: The second asset should not contain any warranties at all? And should the first asset contains all warranties?

Comment: It should, But the information should not be the same. The source is not what is causing it. It repeats what is put in the warranty information instead of moving on to the next iteration in the collection.

Comment: So the first asset should have first warranty, second asset second warranty and so on?

Comment: First asset will have a set of warranties. The second asset will have a set of warranties and so on and so forth. That information comes from the 'var xlWarranty'

Comment: Okay. Can you provide an example of **correct** result?